# Show better diff when asserting 'containsAll' in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock, assertions

I need to perform assertion that a collection contains all elements from the other collection.

The following test should fail, because first collection doesn't contain `7` from the second one:

```
def first = [6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
def second = [3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6]
expect:
first.containsAll(second)
```

However, test failure is not readable at all. It is not clear that just `7` is missing:

```
left.containsAll(right)
|    |           |
|    false       [3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6]
[6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

AssertJ deals with that much better:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <[6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]>
to contain:
 <[3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6]>
but could not find:
 <[7]>
```

What kind of assertion would be idiomatic in Spock to get **better failure messages for `containsAll`**?

Comment: I think spock has better support to compare strings, so you can try `first.toString() == second.toString()`. Of course it's a dirty hack...

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could hack around and do something like `(right - left).isEmpty()` which should print out the elements that are in right but not in left.

It is a bit of a hacky way, but really anything I can come up with

Answer (score 4):

I agree that AssertJ has better messages and you could use AssertJ in the Spock tests.

Other than that you have to define the assert message your self like

```
assert first.containsAll(second), "$first does not contain all from $second. Missing elements: " + (second - first)
```